# Is there something special about a MVC controller called properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

After trying to work this out for ages, thinking about routing conflict and more - I started a separate project from the start.

It looks like an MVC controller called "properties" always returns a 403.14 forbidden message when you try to access the root site (`http://site/properties`) - however, other pages work (`http://site/properties/index`).

It works fine as a controller in an area, but, I just can't create it in the main site.

I was wondering if anyone knows why and what the best way round this is?

Answer (score 3):

In addtion to DavidG's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263788/is-there-something-special-about-a-mvc-controller-called-properties/34264041#34263869).

When you publish the project the compiled build does not have a Properties folder. To solve the issue while developing locally you can set `RouteExistingFiles` to `true` so ASP.NET routing handles all requests.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your project already contains a folder called `Properties` which is mainly used for the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file but has other stuff in there too. The engine used to resolve what files to send to the client prioritises files and folders over routing. so the URL `http://site/properties` is trying to server content from there, which is ultimately blocked anyway.